QGIS: Field Calculator number line segments grouped by street
In QGIS I have a line layer of Streets that are made up of about 1900 segments. Using the field calculator I would like to create a new column that contains a sequential number grouped by the street name.
I went ahead and made this picture, in case I couldn't make myself clear:


The linked question is virtually the same and the answer should work, despite being a bit older now. To be fair, finding it wasn't that easy ;-)

Nice one thanks
